# Lucene "Or Queries"

Tags: search, lucene

I am new in Lucene, I am trying to make a search something like this

```
 content="some thext" and (id ="A" or id="B" or id="c")
```

I am really lost with that, could you help me

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe the "Grouping" section in the [Query Parser Syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Grouping) provides the answer:

```
(jakarta OR apache) AND website
```

I suspect you should make your operators (`and`, `or`) upper case. As well, I don't think you can use the equals operator (use a colon instead).

```
content:"some thext" AND (id:"A" OR id:"B" OR id:"c")
```

Comment: Thank you... it was so successful your help

Comment: you could simplify it to: `content:"some thext" AND id:("A" OR "B" OR "c")`

Answer (score 27):

```
BooleanQuery mainQuery = new BooleanQuery();

TermQuery contentFilter = new TermQuery(new Term("content", "some text"));
mainQuery.add(contentFilter, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

BooleanQuery idFilter = new BooleanQuery();
idFilter.setMinimumNumberShouldMatch(1);
idFilter.add(new TermQuery(new Term("id", A)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
idFilter.add(new TermQuery(new Term("id", B)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
idFilter.add(new TermQuery(new Term("id", C)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
mainQuery.Add(idFilter, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Comment: Looks like `moduleFilter` should be changed to `idFilter`. Anyway +1 for answer.

Comment: An explanation I found useful (from the Occur javadocs): For a BooleanQuery with no Occur.MUST clauses, one or more Occur.SHOULD clauses must match a document for the BooleanQuery to match.

Answer (score 0):

BooleanQuery is deprecated now.

New syntax looks like this. (should == OR, must == AND)

```
val searchManager = Search.getSearchManager(cache)
val queryBuilder = searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass(classTag[T].runtimeClass).get()
val luceneQuery = queryBuilder.bool()
luceneQuery.should(new TermQuery(new Term("type", "lala"))
luceneQuery.createQuery()
```